# Criar coluna 'timer' no SQL

Tags: sql

É possivel fazer uma coluna do tipo timer, que calcula 24 horas? Por exemplo, o PHP inicia esse timer nessa coluna, e até ele zerar o usuário é impedido de executar tal ação. Porém, quando ele zera, volta para 24:00:00 e só começa quando o usuário executar o processo que só pode ser feito de 24 em 24 horas.

Atualização: Consegui adicionar a tabela a data e a hora perfeitamente. Só estou com dúvidas de como comparar esta data registrada no SQL e a data atual para ver se ja se passaram 24 horas...

Imagem da tabela SQL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que é mais fácil resolver isso com uma coluna datetime. Assim o PHP consulta a coluna, verifica se passaram mais do que 24 horas entre a data actual e a da coluna, e faz o que tem a fazer.
Depois disso actualiza a coluna com a data actual.

Comment: Fiz como você falou. Porém agora como eu comparo as duas para ver se passaram 24 horas?

Comment: Você pode usar a função `date_diff()` se tiver o PHP 5.3+, porém você pode fazer isso direto no sql usando a consulta `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_vote)`.

Comment: Interessante esta função `TIMEDIFF`. E ela retorna em horas o resultado?

Comment: @Guilherme a forma mais fácil de ver o output da função é fazer um teste em MySQL. a função devolve o tempo entre as duas datas, com horas, minutos e segundos...

Comment: Utilizei o método do amigo BlunT acima. Obrigado.